# UITextView with Gesture Recognizer - Conditionally Forward Touch to Parent View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITextView` embedded in a `UITableViewCell`.

The text view has scrolling disabled, and grows in height with the text in it.

The text view has a link-like section of text that is attributed with  a different color and underlined, and I have a **tap gesture recognizer** attached to the text view that detects whether the user tapped on the "link" portion of the text or not *(This is accomplished using the text view's `layoutManager` and `textContainerInset` to detect whether the tap falls within the 'link' or not. It's basically a custom hit test function).*

---

**I want the table view cell to receive the tap and become selected when the user "misses" the link portion of the text view,** but can't figure out how to do it.

---

The text view has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `true`. However, this does not block the touches from reaching the table view cell when there is no gesture recognizer attached.

Conversely, if I set it to `false`, for some reason cell selection stops altogether, even when tapping *outside* of the text view's bounds (but the gesture recognizer **still works...** *WHY?*).

---

#### What I've Tried

I have tried overriding `gestureRecognizer(_ :shouldReceive:)`, but even when I return `false`, the table view cell does not get selected...

I have also tried implementing `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)`, but there too, even if I perform my hit test and return `false`, the cell does not get the tap.

---

**How can I forward the missed taps back to the cell, to highlight it?**

Comment: Would it be possible to create a custom class for UITextView and override the ```pointInside:withEvent```, and in this method you can do the link hit logic, if it missies return false, that should forward the touches to the cell.

Comment: @danypata Yes, I thought about that, but was hoping there's a more elegant solution that does not require additional subclassing...

Comment: I think the below answer is more elegant than my brute force suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying [Swapnil Luktuke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553405/433373)(to the extent that I understood it, at least) to no avail, and every possible combination of:

- Implementing the methods of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`,
- Overriding `UITapGestureRecognizer`,
- Conditionally calling `ignore(_:for:)`, etc.

*(perhaps in my desperation I missed something obvious, but who knows...)*

...I gave up and decided to follow the suggestion by @danyapata in the comments to my question, and **subclass UITextView**.

Partly based on code found on [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/swifty-approach-to-handling-uitextviews-with-links-in-cells-d89e0e4b83d1), I came up with this `UITextView` subclass:

```
import UIKit

/**
 Detects taps on subregions of its attributed text that correspond to custom,
 named attributes.

 - note: If no tap is detected, the behavior is equivalent to a text view with
 `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false` (i.e., touches "pass through"). The
 same behavior doesn't seem to be easily implemented using just stock
 `UITextView` and gesture recognizers (hence the need to subclass).
 */
class LinkTextView: UITextView {

    private var tapHandlersByName: [String: [(() -> Void)]] = [:]

    /**
     Adds a custom block to be executed wjhen a tap is detected on a subregion
     of the **attributed** text that contains the attribute named accordingly.
     */
    public func addTapHandler(_ handler: @escaping(() -> Void), forAttribute attributeName: String) {
        var handlers = tapHandlersByName[attributeName] ?? []
        handlers.append(handler)
        tapHandlersByName[attributeName] = handlers
    }

    // MARK: - Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonSetup()
    }

    private func commonSetup() {
        self.delaysContentTouches = false
        self.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.isEditable = false
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    // MARK: - UIView

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let attributeName = self.attributeName(at: point), let handlers = tapHandlersByName[attributeName], handlers.count > 0 else {
            return nil // Ignore touch
        }
        return self // Claim touch
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        // find attribute name
        guard let touch = touches.first, let attributeName = self.attributeName(at: touch.location(in: self)) else {
            return
        }

        // Execute all handlers for that attribute, once:
        tapHandlersByName[attributeName]?.forEach({ (handler) in
            handler()
        })
    }

    // MARK: - Internal Support

    private func attributeName(at point: CGPoint) -> String? {
        let location = CGPoint(
            x: point.x - self.textContainerInset.left,
            y: point.y - self.textContainerInset.top)

        let characterIndex = self.layoutManager.characterIndex(
            for: location,
            in: self.textContainer,
            fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        guard characterIndex < self.textStorage.length else {
            return nil
        }

        let firstAttributeName = tapHandlersByName.allKeys.first { (attributeName) -> Bool in
            if self.textStorage.attribute(NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: attributeName), at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) != nil {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return firstAttributeName
    }
}
```

---

As ususal, I'll wait a couple of days before accepting my own answer, just in case something better shows up...

Answer (score 1):

Keep all your views active (i.e. user interaction enabled).

Loop through the text view's gestures and disable the ones you do not need.

Loop through the table view's `gestureRecognisers` array, and make them depend on the text view's custom tap gesture using [requireGestureRecognizerToFail](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-requiregesturerecognizertofail).

If its a static table view, you can do this in view did load. For a dynamic table view, do this in 'willDisplayCell' for the text view cell.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work at all. Ideally, I would prefer to contain all code within the table view **cell**...